# I want set 30 rpm in Wheel Collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a robot with a wheel to which I have applied a script to rotate the wheel and a "wheel collider" component with these values:

[image]

I would like to know what values ​​I have to modify to get the robot wheel to rotate at 30 rpm, since it is going to move around an office and it is seen to rotate very fast.

Comment: The rotation of the wheel is controlled via properties that are accessible in scripting (motorTorque, brakeTorque etc).  It's not as simple as just setting a specific RPM, but controlling the speed of rotation will be done through the script you have for rotating the wheel.  The values in your screen shot are more generally to do with how the collider interacts with the physics system/other objects.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, since it was a simple wheel and I just wanted it to give the effect of simple movement, what I did was this script.

```
public class WheelRotateAroundCylinder : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform wheel;
    private bool rotate = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        wheel = transform;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(rotate)
        {
            wheel.Rotate(0, -2, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            wheel.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    public void isRotate(bool hasRotate)
    {
        if(hasRotate)
        {
            this.rotate = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.rotate = false;
        }
    }
}
```